# I want to use google my business api to fetch business locations reviews, so need details on the steps

Tags: google-my-business-api

I want to get reviews from multiple google business locations, using my google business API (in PHP) but not able to find out the steps to do that.

Anyone, please help me in sharing the steps to do that.